# connecting two docker containers nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I'm trying to connect two conainers using networks docker, but for some reason I'm getting a error:

MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [db:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.22.0.3:27017

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    image: nodejs
    container_name: nodejs
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: 
      - .env
    environment:
      - MONGO_USERNAME=$MONGO_USERNAME
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=$MONGO_PASSWORD
      - MONGO_HOSTNAME=db
      - MONGO_PORT=$MONGO_PORT
      - MONGO_DB=$MONGO_DB 
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/app
      - node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules
    networks:
      - app-network
    command: /home/node/app/node_modules/.bin/nodemon app.js
  db:
    image: mongo:4.2.9-bionic
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: 
      - .env
    environment: 
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=$MONGO_USERNAME
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MONGO_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db
    networks:
      - app-network
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  dbdata:
  node_modules:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that MongoDB inside the container has not yet started when your Node.js app is trying to connect to it?

You should try marking `nodejs` service as [dependent on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) `db` service.

Comment: I did what you recommended and can now connect to the container, thanks ;)